# Initialize dialogflow messenger chat by custom data

Tags: dialogflow-es

I need to initiate a dialogflow messenger chat by passing custom data. In a flight booking confirmation page, I need to display possible ancillaries of that booking. So I need to initialize the messenger by passing the trip-id, getting possible ancillary details from a database and display cards of ancillaries. Because the user is in confirmation page, user does not want to enter trip details again. I have tried passing data as HTML attributes like tripId="1111111", but did not work. I can pass the user id using 'user-id' attribute, but for my case that is not enough, I need to pass some other custom data. Any help will be really appreciated!!

Comment: can you share some code for each step in your explanation?

Comment: As per the documentation, I've added dialoflow messenger in my html page like below: -
        <df-messenger intent="ANCIALLARY_LIST" chat-title="title" agent-id="xxx" language-code="en" expand="true" ></df-messenger>

Comment: If I have 3 pages in my application - list, book and confirmation - how can I send the current context information (page:'list', user:'123', bookingDetails:{.. ..}) to dialoglow so that in the embedded chat window, I can show suggestions based on the current user activity(page). For example, if the user arrives at the conformation page, because I passed the conformation number to dialogflow somehow, I can see possible ancillaries of the booking. For example when user arrives the conformation page, chat window shows -'here are some interesting ancillaries for you - book a taxi, hotel' etc.